# How can i simplify nullable to not null parameter assignment?

Tags: kotlin, notnull

I have a situation, when i need to assign a lot of nullable properties at data class to not null ones. I'm using too much of

```
requireNotNull(parameter) { "Missing parameter" }
```

For example, i have an external data class like this:

```
data class External(
    val first: String? = null,
    val second: String? = null,
    val third: String? = null,
    val fourth: String? = null,
)
```

And i have a class that is used with only not null values of external class, like:

```
data class Internal(
    val first: String,
    val second: String,
    val third: String,
    val fourth: String,
)
```

So when i'm mapping external on internal, i have to write like this:

```
val internal = Internal(
    first = requireNotNull(external.first) { "Missing first." },
    second = requireNotNull(external.second ) { "Missing second." },
    third = requireNotNull(external.third ) { "Missing third." },
    fourth = requireNotNull(external.fourth ) { "Missing fourth." }
)
```

In fact, i have more than twenty such properties and i don't think that requireNotNull is very good solution in such case. Could anyone advice something better?

Comment: Well if you're sure they're not null when mapping, surely just asserting the call would be best?

Comment: I'd better fail on parameter mapping without making a call, maybe...